# Send Instance of Generic as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics, cross-reference

I have an abstract *Group* class and an abstract *Member* class. Group class has a field (property) of Member class called *member*, and Member has a field of Group class called *group*.

They both must be inherited that way, so we have *DerGroup* and *DerMember* and DerGroup has the *member* field of ***DerMember*** and DerMember has the *group* field of ***Group*** class.

I am trying to use Generics for that.

```
abstract class Member
{
    public Group<Member> group;
    public void Init(Group<Member> grp)
    {
        group = grp;
    }
}

abstract class Group<T> where T : Member
{
    public T member;
    public void InitMember()
    {
        // Here I have an Error: Can't convert Group<T> to Group<Member>
        member.Init(this);
    }
}
```

How do I send **this** Group instance to its Member instance if Group is Generic? I am using Generics to be able to inherit Group and Member classes and save their relations. Like that:

```
class Student : Member {}
class ClassRoom<T> : Group<Member> where T : Student {}
```

So we can have this: typeof(ClassRoom.member) = **Student**, and not **Member**

Give me any help of how to properly declare `Member.Init()` function or get this done.

Comment: Is this a simplificated/contreived of what you need? There are no abstract methods to be implemented

Comment: `member.Init((Group<Member>) (object) this)` is ugly, but it does work.

Comment: I dont actually need them abstract. It was just for showing that Group and Member are going to be inherited.

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking of the casting to requested type, but I thought there is a better way to do it.

Comment: There probably is, if you rewrite your code to be more based around interfaces (which can use covariance) and/or dispense with unnecessary genericity and rely more on inheritance. But if we take your code as fixed and assume your use of generics is necessary, I'm pretty sure the cast is equally necessary and unavoidable. Note that the conversion is not safe, and will fail at runtime if you declare `class ClassRoom<T> : Group<Student> where T : Student`. The fact that this declaration is possible and seems reasonable already suggests your design might be suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you may have gone down the GRHOM - Generic Rabbit Hole of Madness. If you look around you'll see my claw marks.

The relationship between these classes is very difficult to follow because it indicates that a group can only have one member and a member can only belong to one group.

What it looks like you're trying to do is circular. You're trying to ensure that groups only have one sort of member, and members only belong to groups which contain  members which are only members of that sort of group... etc.

The question is, why do you need to constrain this both ways? Given this:

```
class Group<T> : Group where T : Member
```

You've already ensured that a `Group` can only contain `Member` or a subclass of `Member` - whatever `T` is when you define your concrete class.

Why, then, does a `Member` need to also specify that it can only belong to groups which can only have it as a member? That constraint has already been accomplished.

Assuming that groups must contain references to members and members to groups, 
you could do this:

```
abstract class Member
{
    private List<Group> Groups { get; } = new List<Group>();

    internal void AddGroup(Group group)
    {
        Groups.Add(group);
    }
}

abstract class Group
{
    protected List<Member> Members { get; } = new List<Member>();
}

abstract class Group<TMember> :Group  where TMember : Member
{
    void AddMember(TMember member)
    {
        Members.Add(member);
        member.AddGroup(this);
    }
}
```

Now groups can be constrained by the type of members, but members has a reference to a non-constrained set of groups.

It might be simpler just to avoid having members reference groups. If you want to know which groups a member is in, query the groups to see which ones contain a given member.

Comment: Saw your claw marks...  thanks for this, I think I made my way out! Group inheriting Group is magic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you're trying to build with these classes (I mean, your core business), but you could introduce an interface:

```
abstract class Member
{
    public IGroup<Member> group;
    public void Init(IGroup<Member> grp)
    {
        group = grp;
    }
}

interface IGroup<T> where T : Member
{
    T member { get; set; }
}

abstract class Group<T> : IGroup<Member>
{
    public Member member { get; set; }

    public void InitMember()
    {
        member.Init(this);
    }
}

class Student : Member { }

class ClassRoom<T> : Group<Student> where T : Student { }
```

Working [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cX4Fao).

Comment: Can you show how to test this code? Will this work: 
var cr = new ClassRoom(); 
//cr.member.GetType() must be Student.

Comment: @user1537809 sure, I've just added a fiddle.

Comment: Ok... But what is the point of trick with Interface if you do explicit assignment of member field in line "var c = new ClassRoom<Student>() { member = new Student() };" ? That is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I want to inherit ClassRoom from Group, and Student from Member so that ClassRoom's filed member becomes type of Student.

Comment: @user1537809 using interfaces has nothing to do with explicit assignment of member field, you'd need to do so even if you didn't use interfaces. You need to initialize the member field with something like `new Student()`, otherwise the `InitMember` method would throw an excetion, because `member` would be null. On the other hand, it's not necessary to explicit assign `new Student()` to `member` in order to make *ClassRoom's field member becomes type of Student*, if you write this code you'll notice `member` is of type `Student`, regardless of `member = new Student()`.